# Uncertainty after associated User as a Foreign Key in another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a question about associated User as a Foreign Key in another model.

when i associated User as a Foreign Key in my Post model, i save with:

```
post.user = self.request.user
```

i want the username be exactly the user that post something, and it should not allow to change and edit the user right, because if i can change the user in the specific post, then the post is not belong to that person already.

but when i go to the admin and try to change the user in post model, i can edit/change the user in the specific post and the post is no longer the same person, should this suppose to happen or i miss something?

Also, i didnt receive any error when i save the post, everything is fine.

Thank you, hope you guys understand what i saying.

models.py

```
 class PostModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length =200, unique = True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        file = models.FileField(upload_to="post", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['gif','png','jpg','jpeg','mp4'])])
        description = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

views.py

```
class PostView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','file','description']
    template_name = 'post/post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post= form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = self.request.user
        post.save()
        return super(PostView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Well, no, I don't really understand. Of course you can edit the fields of a model in the admin, that's what it's for

Comment: @DanielRoseman , i thought even admin should not have the authorities to changes the user of specific post, now i understand. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are asking for. Yet Django admin is for site data administration and thus it is just defaultly allowed for administrator directly modifying the data from admin site.

If you are looking for a way that letting the fields not be able to modified even by the administrators in admin site, you have to do further customized configuration such as setting [`ModelAdmin.list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) to that field.

Comment: I think you know what i mean. So even admin should have the authority to change the User foreign key right ?

Comment: Of course. Yet this also can be customized. Just read the pages about [django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/) and [user permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/) in official docs and you may get further information